# Restore PostgreSQL dump with new primary key values

Tags: postgresql

I've got a problem with a PostgreSQL dump / restore. We have a production appliaction running with PostgresSQL 8.4. I need to create some values in the database in the testing environment and then import just this chunk of data into the production environment. The data is generated by the application and I need to use this approach because it needs testing before going into production.

Now that I described the environment, here is my problem:

In the testing database, I leave nothing but the data I need to move to the production database. The data is spread across multiple tables linked with foreign keys with multiple levels (like a tree). I then use pg_dump to export the desired tables into binary format.

When I try to import, the database will correctly import the root table entries with new primary key values, but does not import any of the data from the other tables. I believe that the problem is that foreign keys on child tables no longer recognizes the new primary keys.

Is there a way to achieve such an import which will update all the primary key values of all affected tables in the tree to correct serial (auto increment) values automatically and also update all foreign keys according to these new primary key values?

I have and idea how to do this with assistance of programming language while connected to both databases, but that would be very problematic to achieve for me since I don't have direct access to customers production server.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That one seems to me like a complex migration issue. You can create PL/pgSQL migration scripts with inserts and use returning to get serials and use as foreign keys for other tables up the tree. I do not know the structure of your tree but in some cases reading sequence values in advance into arrays may be required due to complexity or performance reasons.

Other approach can be to examine production sequence values and estimate sequence values that will not be used in the near future. Fabricate test data in the test environment to have serial values that will not collide with production sequence values. Then load that data into the prod database and adjust sequence values of the prod environment so that test sequence values will not be used. It will leave a gap in your ID sequence so you must examine whether anything (like other processes) rely on the sequence values to be continuos.

Comment: Thanks for a swift answer! The gap could be a problem since the IDs of various records are used by the customer in invoices, offers, etc. But I will look into the PL/pgSQL language. I'm not very experienced with it, but I see what I can do with it.

Comment: Your test data will take up sequence values so prepare to have gaps anyway. Of course you can delete test data and modify sequences but if users use the production environment in the timeframe of testing you cannot do this because your database will become messed up.

Database tools can export data as insert statements which can serve as a starting point to export data. You can use INSERT INTO table (cols) VALUES (vals) RETURNING idcolumn to get the value of ID. You can use INSERT with sub-selects as well. INSERT WITH is also a handy tool.
Wish you good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for suggestions Peter. I actually came up with another possibility - it can create small gaps, but I have more control - I created a script that advances the sequences in the production environment in all the affected tables by the number of rows I wish to insert, + some small reserve. Then I generated the data to insert with starting sequence at the start of the production "gap" and then simply insert :-).

This solution works and the gaps created are minimal. I accepted your answer since the idea came out of it. Thanks.

Comment: It would be awesome to see examples